# php-How can i put this IF condition inside switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Please help me for correcting this code,i want put if inside switch:

```
switch ($urlcomecatid) {

 if ($urlcomeparentid == 1 || $urlcomeparentid == 2 || $urlcomeparentid == 3)
  break;

case "50":
case "51":
case "52":
case "109":
case "110":
    //do nothing and exit from switch
    break;
default:
    header ("Location:http://www.example.com/tech/tech.php"); exit();
    break;
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct code should be something like

```
switch ($urlcomecatid) {
    case "50":
    case "51":
    case "52":
    case "109":
    case "110":
        //do nothing and exit from switch
        break;
    default:
        if ($urlcomeparentid == 1 || $urlcomeparentid == 2 || $urlcomeparentid == 3)
            break;
        header ("Location:http://www.example.com/tech/tech.php"); exit();
        break;
 }
```

Comment: <?php

$a=34;


switch ($a) {
    case "50":
    case "51":
    case "52":
    case "109":
    case "110":
        //do nothing and exit from switch
        break;
    default:
        if ($a == 34 || $a == 2 || $a == 3)
  {
   echo "success";
   
  }
  else{
        header ("Location:http://www.ankitdev.in"); exit();
        break;
  }
 }
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` instead of the `switch`.

```
<?php
if(!in_array($urlcomeparentid, array(1, 2, 3) && !in_array($urlcomecatid, array('50', '51', '52', '109', '110')){
    header ("Location:http://www.example.com/tech/tech.php");
    exit();
}
```

You should avoid `exit()` as it kills the rest of your script which is a potential source of problems when you debug.